# Is my dog obese for his measurements?

Tags: dogs, weight

Here's some backstory. I adopted my now 3-year-old Staffordshire Terrier Mix at 3 months old (It is unknown what else he is mixed with.) He's a bred hound-type dog and has plenty of energy. He walks three miles per day at least, and I play with him regularly at night. He eats a cup of Rachel Ray dry dog food once at night and once in the morning with training treats in between.

Here's my issue. When I adopted him, I was told he would be about 40-60 lbs (18-27 kg) but since his parents and other mix isn't known, this was a guess on the adoption agency's part. He's 3 now and you can't see his ribs but you can feel them pretty well. We recently went to the vet and he weighed in at 72 lbs (32.7 kg) and the vet said he was obese.

Again you can feel his ribs quite well and I don't believe that is a mark of an obese dog.

He's about 18 inches (45.7 cm) tall and about 21 inches (53.3 cm) long.
Is this really overweight for his measurements in specific?

If this is really is overweight, are there any dietary changes I should make? What else can I do about it?

Edit: This was closed for lack of clarity/detail and I'm not sure how to add any more detail, as I disclosed his feeding and exercise habits and measurements.

Comment: If I read right, you did not mention the size of your dog. Only some guess of breed and the weight would not be enough to answer this question :) A photo would also help.

Comment: And do you have any reason to doubt your vet’s assessment, considering they have seen the dog and we haven’t?

Comment: @Stephie yes, you can feel his ribs and that is not the mark of an obese dog.

Comment: @Allerleirauh I edited in his measurments!

Comment: If compared to lists of dog breeds that include height and weight, such as https://ncraoa.com/breed-weight-height/ 72 lbs is generally quite a bit more than the weights listed for dog breeds of a similar height.

Comment: I am not sure I understand lbs. 72 lbs makes approximately 163000 carats, right?

Comment: @Kai would you mind turning this comment into an answer?

Comment: @C.Koca yes, that conversion is correct

Comment: Are the 18 inches shoulder height? And I guess he’s got short hair like a Staffordshire terrier?

Comment: Here, the lack of clarity is not the description of the dog, it is the lack of a photo of the dog. We can't feel the ribs of your dog for you, but we can make some deductions from the photos.

Comment: you need to post a picture of your dog,take a picture transfer it to your pc and edit your question and upload the picture(s) to your question.the body type of a dog differs a lot and what is normal weight for one can be grossly overweight for an other body type.